# Download file from Details View MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Hello I try to download file from server.

Here is my controller

```
 public ActionResult Downloads()
    {
        var dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Content/AnnFiles/"));
        System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dir.GetFiles("*.*"); List<string> items = new List<string>();
        foreach (var file in fileNames)
        {
            items.Add(file.Name);
        }
        return View(items);
    }

    public FileResult Download(string file)
    {

        var FileVirtualPath = "~/Content/AnnFiles/" + file;
        return File(FileVirtualPath, "application/force-download", Path.GetFileName(FileVirtualPath));
    }
```

and in my view

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", "announcement", new { id = Model.file})
```

It doesn't work. It returns the error

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Myprojects\MyprojectName\MyprojectName\Content\AnnFiles\'
```

Any idea?
thank you

Comment: In ActionLink you pass "id" parameter while you should use "file" as declared in Download action

Comment: thank you, I changes it to  @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", "announcement",  Model.file). But it returns the same error. When debug with firebug it is rendering the link as <a length="21" href="/announcement/Download?Length=12">Download</a>

Comment: I think the ancor helper must be like "@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", "announcement", new { file= Model.file})" , that should be rendered as "/announcement/Download?file=[yourModel.File]"

Comment: If you add a breakpoint, what does FileVirtualPath show as?

Comment: now it renders <a file="announcement_1311.png" href="/announcement/Download?Length=12">Download</a>

Comment: @glosrob FileVirtualPath its hows Empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the following overload;

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", "announcement", new { file = Model.file}, null);
```

Adding the null parameter at the end uses the following:

**[LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, String, RouteValueDictionary, IDictionary)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29)**

**[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E1aGyk)**